# How to detect all available actions a webelement has using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, action

I am trying to write a program that goes through every element on a webpage and notes whether it has any actions associated to it.

Is there any way that I would be able to detect all the possible actions a single webelement has using javascript and/or if needed Jquery? Even if someone just has an example of being able to detect one action (eg. a click or a hover) that'd be great too.

Comment: your tags say "javascript" and "css" but it seems like you want to write a program that is written in some other language? like something in C that reads the webpage and finds elements with a javascript function attached?

Comment: well everything is going to be executed through java, but the scripts that actually detect whether an element has an action associated to it will be ran in javascript and if needed, JQuery

Comment: So you basically want to check if there is a `document.getElementById('abc').addEventListener('click,func,false);`
for each element?

Comment: but doesn't addEventListener only return something if an action has occurred? I just need to be able to look at the DOM for a page and be able to tell what all the POSSIBLE actions on any given element is without performing actions on it.

Comment: ahh, i think I understand now. You could parse through the HTML and check for tags. each div will have a click and hover, each textbox will have onFocus...etc.